# How to receive pickle via subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, pickle

getPickle.py

```
import pickle
import subprocess

cmd = ['rsh', 'host1', 'sendPickle.py']
p  = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
results = pickle.load(stdout)
print results
```

sendPickle.py

```
import pickle
import sys

to_return = {'a':1, 'b': 2}
pickle.dump(to_return, sys.stdout)
```

OUTPUT:

```
File "getPickle" line 10, in <module>
    results = pickle.load(stdout)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline'
```

What can I do to get pickle back from stdout?

Thank you

Comment: With python 3.8 I needed to use `sys.stdout.buffer`, i.e. `pickle.dump(to_return, sys.stdout.buffer)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pickle.loads` to load the pickle from a string. `pickle.load` is for loading from a stream.

Two unrelated remarks:

- if you are using Python 2, you probably want to `import cPickle as pickle` because the C version is many time faster and just as powerful.
- unless you specifically want to support older Python versions, it is a good idea to use `protocol=-1` on the dump side in order specify the latest Pickle protocol, which is more efficient than the default lowest/oldest version.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns If you have an idea how to improve an answer, please suggest it in a comment before editing the answer to make the change yourself.

Comment: My code example was a clarification of your somewhat obtuse one-line remark, which made what you are saying crystal clear.  Apologies if you were somehow offended.  So… I suggest that you add a snippet of code, much like the one that I added, so it's clear… as your answer is obtuse, and this is an unusual case of pairing `dump` and `loads`.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns No offense was taken. I don't consider my answer obtuse, but the opposite - clear and to the point. If you believe you can provide a better explanation, feel free to post a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

@user4815162342 gives the correct answer. To make it crystal clear, here's example code showing how to retrieve the pickled object.

Note that it's a bit of an unusual case to pair `dump` and `loads`, but that's what needs to be done as `p.communicate` returns the string from stdout.

```
>>> import pickle
>>> import subprocess as sp
>>> cmd = ['python', 'sendPickle.py']
>>> p = sp.Popen(cmd, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
>>> stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
>>> stdout
"(dp0\nS'a'\np1\nI1\nsS'b'\np2\nI2\ns."
>>> results = pickle.loads(stdout)
>>> results
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```