# Return value from subprocess call

Tags: python, subprocess

I have two scripts. I call *Script2* from *Script1* via subprocess.check_output to get a list of production numbers.

Now I want to return the production numbers from Script2, so that I can process them in Script1.

The two scripts are located in different directories.

How can I process the variable *production_numbers* in Script1.

**Script1**

```
 subprocess.check_output(['python', 'C:/PycharmProjects/Platform/ERPProgramm/crawl_prodnr.py')
```

**Script2**

```
import requests

def query(resource):
    r = requests.get('http://10.105.11.20:8080/webapp/api/v1/' + resource,
        headers={'AuthenticationToken': 'xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx'}
    )
    return r.json()

d = query('productionOrder') 
production_numbers = []


for e in d['result']:
    production_numbers.append(e['productionOrderNumber'])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to receive pickle via subprocess.Popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34181033/how-to-receive-pickle-via-subprocess-popen)

Comment: Sorry, the other thread is not helping me with my exact problem :/

Answer (score 0):

You can print `production_numbers` at the end of Script2.

Then use `my_output =  subprocess.check_output(['python', 'C:/PycharmProjects/Platform/ERPProgramm/crawl_prodnr.py')` in Script1 to call Script2 and get the printed message in `my_output`.